# How to view font file on Arch Linux with KDE desktop?

Tags: fonts, archlinux, kde-plasma

I want to install some other font for my Arch Linux with KDE desktop, but it seems to be that there is no applications in KDE to view font file. Are there some nice applications to view font file for Arch Linux ? I searched for a long time and couldn't find the right one.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting interface can manage and view font files

Comment: Thanks. It work. But it seems to be that the setting interface can not recognize those .ttc font file.

Comment: I try to add some .ttc font file in setting interface font management, but it can not recognize them.

Comment: 你要用微软的字体吗，可以在[ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Microsoft_fonts_(%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87))查看安装方法                                                                                                     ================================================================Do you want to use Microsoft fonts? You can find it in [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Microsoft_fonts_(%E7%AE%80%E4%BD%93%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87)) View the installation method

Comment: No, I am just trying to use some open source monospaced font which is packed in .ttc file. This method seems to work for any .ttc font file. Thanks again.